# What is the best way to return completed Task?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

What is the best way to return a completed [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) object?

It is possible to write [`Task.Delay(0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873.aspx), or [`Task.FromResult<bool>(true)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922.aspx) whatever.

But what is the most efficient way?

Comment: What is the reason for this? You don't need a Task for this. just call the method.

Comment: @I4V it is common practice when sometimes an operation needs work but sometimes it isn't and can be done efficiently without needing async

Comment: Here's a good article on edge-cases like this: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html. tl;dr it's okay to leave the warning, as this approach will avoid a lot of the pitfalls of removing the `async` keyword.

Comment: _"attempt to use return Task.FromResult(mockToken); gives: error CS4016"_ -- that's why you don't make the method `async` when you just return a task object.

Comment: There is a flaw in your question. You said "When async Task<T> required by interface", but an interface can never require `async`. It can only require that the return value is `Task<T>`.

Comment: Yip I realized a day later, just drop the async and the method signature is still valid for the interface.  The answer comment regarding exception semantics was also partially what I was concerned about.

Answer (score 5):

Answer from Stephen Toub (MSFT):

> If you want a new Task object each time, Task.FromResult is the most
>   efficient.  Task.Delay(0) in its current implementation will return a
>   cached task, but that's an implementation detail.  If you want to use
>   a cached task, you should cache one yourself, e.g. private static
>   readonly Task s_completedTask = Task.FromResult(true); and then use
>   s_completedTask.

Comment: Andrii, can you give the link to cited by you Toub's statement? Google does not return any results on searching phrases from your quote

Comment: I asked him directly and posted answer here because I think that it is important

Answer (score 4):

Task.FromResult would be the most direct. It also includes inbuilt results for a few common integers etc. However, if your value is not an "obvious" value (and won't have inbuilt handling) but is likely to be returned often in your scenario - then you can create your own cached result in a field (maybe static if appropriate) - but it is important to cache the Task, not the result itself.l - otherwise just use Task.FromResult each time.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little demo which shows the difference in exception handling between methods marked and not marked with async.

```
public Task<string> GetToken1WithoutAsync() => throw new Exception("Ex1!");

// Warning: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider ...
public async Task<string> GetToken2WithAsync() => throw new Exception("Ex2!");  

public string GetToken3Throws() => throw new Exception("Ex3!");
public async Task<string> GetToken3WithAsync() => await Task.Run(GetToken3Throws);

public async Task<string> GetToken4WithAsync() { throw new Exception("Ex4!"); return await Task.FromResult("X");} 


public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = new Program();

    try { var task1 = p.GetToken1WithoutAsync(); } 
    catch( Exception ) { Console.WriteLine("Throws before await.");};

    var task2 = p.GetToken2WithAsync(); // Does not throw;
    try { var token2 = await task2; } 
    catch( Exception ) { Console.WriteLine("Throws on await.");};

    var task3 = p.GetToken3WithAsync(); // Does not throw;
    try { var token3 = await task3; } 
    catch( Exception ) { Console.WriteLine("Throws on await.");};

    var task4 = p.GetToken4WithAsync(); // Does not throw;
    try { var token4 = await task4; } 
    catch( Exception ) { Console.WriteLine("Throws on await.");};
}
```

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
Throws before await.
Throws on await.
Throws on await.
Throws on await.
```

*Moved (and edited) from [When async Task<T> required by interface, how to get return variable without compiler warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58634159/when-async-taskt-required-by-interface-how-to-get-return-variable-without-com/58634221#58634221))*

Comment: Except that will change the behavior of `GetToken()` in the event that `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` throws.

Comment: `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` doesn't throw.

Comment: Even if it did throw, I don't feel it matters: the exact exceptional behavior would be different, but not in any material way. In either case, the caller will see the exception; in the above example, it will be on the call to `GetToken()`, while if the method is left as `async`, it will be on the `await`. Frankly, the former is better; fail-fast.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that there are scenarios in which this advice will not produce exact equivalent behavior. Knowing whether `GetToken()` can throw an exception synchronously, or will always return a `Task` is an important consideration to users extrapolating from this answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's a fair and an important point. I added a little demo to showcase the concern you brought to light ;)

Comment: Solutions B and C have a performance overhead (minimal, but it's still there) for no benefit.

Answer (score 3):

I think that I am a little late. However, I still want to share this answer, for an updated version.

If you want to return a completed task, you should use the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?view=net-6.0):

```cs
return Task.CompletedTask;
```

This will also automatically set the [status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-taskstatus-rantocompletion) to `RanToCompletion`.

Comment: Note that the `Task.CompletedTask` property was introduced in 2015, and some answers in this thread are older than that.