# Should I worry about "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously" warning

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have a interface which exposes some async methods. More specifically it has methods defined which return either `Task` or `Task<T>`. I am using the async/await keywords.

I am in the process of implementing this interface. However, in some of these methods this implementation doesn't have anything to await. For that reason I am getting the compiler warning "CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously..."

I understand why I am getting these warnings but am wondering whether I should do anything about them in this context. It feels wrong to ignore compiler warnings.

I know I can fix it by awaiting on `Task.Run` but that feels wrong for a method that is only doing a few inexpensive operations. It also sounds like it will add unneeded overhead to the execution but then I am also not sure if that is already there because the `async` keyword is present.

Should I just ignore the warnings or is there a way of working around this that I am not seeing?

Comment: It's going to depend on the specifics.  Are you really sure you want these operations to be performed synchronously?  If you do want them to be performed synchronously, why is the method marked as `async`?

Comment: Just remove the `async` keyword. You can still return a `Task` using `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: In one example it really does just assign some values to properties so I am definitely comfortable with it executing synchronously. It's more specifically about how to handle the compiler warning which seems like could just be the obvious one of removing async keyword

Comment: @BenVoigt Google is full of information about it, in the event that the OP doesn't already know.

Comment: @BenVoigt Didn't Michael Liu already provide that hint? Use `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: @hvd: That was edited into his comment later.

Comment: Re: "Just remove the async keyword." -- What if it's a library is not modifiable by us but requires "async" on its methods? Is there a way to fake it? We are not "webscale", we don't need that bloaty buzzword crap.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

The **async** keyword is merely an implementation detail of a method; it isn’t part of the method signature. If a particular method implementation or override has nothing to await, then just omit the **async** keyword and return a completed task using [Task.FromResult<TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult):

```
public Task<string> Foo()               //    public async Task<string> Foo()
{                                       //    {
    Baz();                              //        Baz();
    return Task.FromResult("Hello");    //        return "Hello";
}                                       //    }
```

If your method return type is [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) instead of [Task<TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1), then return [Task.CompletedTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask):

```
public Task Bar()                       //    public async Task Bar()
{                                       //    {
    Baz();                              //        Baz();
    return Task.CompletedTask;          //
}                                       //    }
```

Note: Task.CompletedTask was added in .NET Framework 4.6. If you’re targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2 or earlier, then you can instead return a completed task of any type and value. `Task.FromResult(0)` seems to be a popular choice:

```
public Task Bar()                       //    public async Task Bar()
{                                       //    {
    Baz();                              //        Baz();
    return Task.FromResult(0);          //
}                                       //    }
```

### Dealing with Exceptions

An exception thrown by a non-**async** method propagates immediately up the call stack, but an exception thrown by an **async** method is stored in the returned Task object and propagates only when the Task is awaited. This makes a big difference if someone calls your method *and then does something else* before awaiting the Task:

```
Task<string> task = Foo();   // If Foo is async and throws an exception,
DoSomethingElse();           // then this line will be executed,
string result = await task;  // and the exception will be rethrown here.
```

If you need to preserve this behavior for a non-**async** method, then wrap the entire method within a **try...catch** statement. Pass any unhandled exception to [Task.FromException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromexception), and return the result:

```
public Task<string> Foo()                       //  public async Task<string> Foo()
{                                               //  {
    try                                         //
    {                                           //
        Baz(); // might throw                   //      Baz();
        return Task.FromResult("Hello");        //      return "Hello";
    }                                           //
    catch (Exception ex)                        //
    {                                           //
        return Task.FromException<string>(ex);  //
    }                                           //
}                                               //  }

public Task Bar()                               //  public async Task Bar()
{                                               //  {
    try                                         //
    {                                           //
        Baz(); // might throw                   //      Baz();
        return Task.CompletedTask;              //
    }                                           //
    catch (Exception ex)                        //
    {                                           //
        return Task.FromException(ex);          //
    }                                           //
}                                               //  }
```

The generic argument to Task.FromException must match the return type of the method.

### Reducing Boilerplate Code

You can use the following helper class to automatically call Task.FromResult and Task.FromException for you:

```
public static class TaskHelper
{
    public static Task FromResultOf(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Task.FromException(ex);
        }
    }

    public static Task<T> FromResultOf<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        try
        {
            return Task.FromResult(func());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Task.FromException<T>(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public Task<string> Foo()               //    public async Task<string> Foo()
{                                       //    {
    return TaskHelper.FromResultOf(     //
        () =>                           //
        {                               //
            Baz();                      //        Baz();
            return "Hello";             //        return "Hello";
        });                             //
}                                       //    }

public Task Bar()                       //    public async Task Bar()
{                                       //    {
    return TaskHelper.FromResultOf(     //
        () =>                           //
        {                               //
            Baz();                      //        Baz();
        });                             //
}                                       //    }
```

Comment: Thanks I think the bit I was missing was the concept of creating a Task that was completed, rather than returning an actual task which like you say would be the same as having the async keyword. Seems obvious now but I just wasn't seeing it!

Comment: Task could do with a static member along the lines of Task.Empty for this purpose. The intention would be a bit clearer and it pains me to think of all these dutiful Tasks that return a zero that is never needed.

Comment: `await Task.FromResult(0)`? How about `await Task.Yield()`?

Comment: @Sushi271: No, in a non-`async` method, you **return** `Task.FromResult(0)` instead of awaiting it.

Comment: Actually NO, async is not just an implementation detail, there are many details around one has to be aware of :). One has to be aware, what part runs synchronously, what part asynchronously, what is the current synchronization context and just for the record, Tasks are always little faster, as there is not state machine behind curtains:).

Comment: I wish the await keyword (or perhaps another keyword specifically for this purpose) would just wrap any non-Task type in a completed Task.

Comment: @wensveen: The `async` keyword does that.  It also generates a compile warning.

Comment: Avoiding the aggravation and extra code of try/catch and Task.FromException is the reason why I mark all Task-returning functions as async, even if they lack an await, and just ignore the warning. I'm so annoyed that this is even a thing, because there's no reason why a caller would expect it.

Comment: @David: To reduce boilerplate code, you might consider using the TaskHelper class that I've added to my answer.

Comment: [Some people put `await Task.CompletedTask;` somewhere in the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096253/) to make the warning go away, but still have automatic "promoting" from `T` to `Task<T>` (or have automatic nongeneric `Task`), including code that have many `return` statements.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Instead of including useless executable code, just use `#pragma warning disable CS1998`, which makes it crystal clear that you're suppressing this particular warning.

Comment: One question about it, if I use async modifier without has the await modifier, it can make the performance bad? Or something like that, because the error from C# says about CPU-Bound.

Comment: @VagnerWentz: When you use the `async` modifier, the compiler generates code for a state machine even if the method doesn't call `await`. This state machine code makes the method a little bigger and takes a bit of time to execute. However, unless the method is called a billion times in a loop, the extra time and CPU overhead are unlikely to be noticeable.

Answer (score 23):

It's perfectly reasonable that some "asynchronous" operations complete synchronously, yet still conform to the asynchronous call model for the sake of polymorphism.

A real-world example of this is with the OS I/O APIs.  Asynchronous and overlapped calls on some devices always complete inline (writing to a pipe implemented using shared memory, for example).  But they implement the same interface as multi-part operations which do continue in the background.

Answer (score 7):

It  might be too late but it might be useful investigation:

There is about inner structure of compiled code (*IL*):

```cs
public static async Task<int> GetTestData()
{
    return 12;
}
```

it becomes to in IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<int32> 
        GetTestData() cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute::.ctor(class [mscorlib]System.Type) = ( 01 00 28 55 73 61 67 65 4C 69 62 72 61 72 79 2E   // ..(UsageLibrary.
                                                                                                                                     53 74 61 72 74 54 79 70 65 2B 3C 47 65 74 54 65   // StartType+<GetTe
                                                                                                                                     73 74 44 61 74 61 3E 64 5F 5F 31 00 00 )          // stData>d__1..
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       52 (0x34)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] class UsageLibrary.StartType/'<GetTestData>d__1' V_0,
           [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> V_1)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void UsageLibrary.StartType/'<GetTestData>d__1'::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<!0> valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::Create()
  IL_000c:  stfld      valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> UsageLibrary.StartType/'<GetTestData>d__1'::'<>t__builder'
  IL_0011:  ldloc.0
  IL_0012:  ldc.i4.m1
  IL_0013:  stfld      int32 UsageLibrary.StartType/'<GetTestData>d__1'::'<>1__state'
  IL_0018:  ldloc.0
  IL_0019:  ldfld      valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> UsageLibrary.StartType/'<GetTestData>d__1'::'<>t__builder'
  IL_001e:  stloc.1
  IL_001f:  ldloca.s   V_1
  IL_0021:  ldloca.s   V_0
  IL_0023:  call       instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::Start<class UsageLibrary.StartType/'<GetTestData>d__1'>(!!0&)
  IL_0028:  ldloc.0
  IL_0029:  ldflda     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> UsageLibrary.StartType/'<GetTestData>d__1'::'<>t__builder'
  IL_002e:  call       instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!0> valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::get_Task()
  IL_0033:  ret
} // end of method StartType::GetTestData
```

And without async and task method:

```
 public static int GetTestData()
 {
      return 12;
 }
```

becomes :

```
.method private hidebysig static int32  GetTestData() cil managed
{
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] int32 V_0)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s   12
  IL_0003:  stloc.0
  IL_0004:  br.s       IL_0006
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method StartType::GetTestData
```

As you could see the big difference between these methods. If you don't use await inside async method and do not care about using of async method (for example API call or event handler) the good idea will convert it to normal sync method (it saves your application performance).

**Updated:**

There is also additional information from [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async#important-info-and-advice):

> async methods need to have an await keyword in their body or they will
> never yield! This is important to keep in mind. If await is not used
> in the body of an async method, the C# compiler will generate a
> warning, but the code will compile and run as if it were a normal
> method. Note that this would also be incredibly inefficient, as the
> state machine generated by the C# compiler for the async method would
> not be accomplishing anything.

Comment: Additonally your final conclusion over the use of `async/await` is vastly oversimplified as you are basing it on your unrealistic example of a single operation that is CPU-bound.  `Task`s when used properly allows for improved application performance and responsiveness due to concurrent tasks (i.e. parallel) and better management and usage of threads

Comment: That is just test simplified example as I said in this post. Also I mentioned about requests to api  and event hendlers where posible using both version of methods (async and regular). Also PO said about using async methods without await inside.  My post was about it but not about properly using `Tasks`. It is sad story that you are not reading whole text of post and doing quickly conclusions.

Comment: There is a difference between a method that returns `int` (as in your case) and one that returns `Task` such as discussed by the OP.  Read _his_ post and the accepted answer **again** instead of taking things personally.  Your answer isn't helpful in this case.  You don't even bother to show the difference between a method that has `await` inside or not.  Now had you done that that would have been _very good_ well worth an upvote

Comment: I guess you are really don't understand difference  between async method and regular ones  that are called with api or event handlers. It was specially mentioned in my post. Sorry for you are missing that **again**.

Answer (score 7):

Only if you are actually calling the method involved, and only if performance is a concern.

This can be demonstrated by writing a program containing the following 4 methods, then decompiling them to [IL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) (note that IL presented may change between runtime versions; the below is from .NET Core 3.1):

```csharp
int FullySync() => 42;

Task<int> TaskSync() => Task.FromResult(42);

// CS1998
async Task<int> NotActuallyAsync() => 42;

async Task<int> FullyAsync() => await Task.Run(() => 42);
```

The first two result in very short method bodies containing exactly what you would expect:

```csharp
.method private hidebysig 
    instance int32 FullySync () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x205e
    // Code size 3 (0x3)
    .maxstack 8

    // return 42;
    IL_0000: ldc.i4.s 42
    IL_0002: ret
} // end of method Program::FullySync

.method private hidebysig 
    instance class [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<int32> TaskSync () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2062
    // Code size 8 (0x8)
    .maxstack 8

    // return Task.FromResult(42);
    IL_0000: ldc.i4.s 42
    IL_0002: call class [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task::FromResult<int32>(!!0)
    IL_0007: ret
} // end of method Program::TaskSync
```

But the presence of the `async` keyword on the last two causes the compiler to generate [asynchronous state machines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/) for those methods:

```csharp
.method private hidebysig 
    instance class [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<int32> NotActuallyAsync () cil managed 
{
    .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute::.ctor(class [System.Runtime]System.Type) = (
        01 00 29 43 53 31 39 39 38 54 65 73 74 2e 50 72
        6f 67 72 61 6d 2b 3c 4e 6f 74 41 63 74 75 61 6c
        6c 79 41 73 79 6e 63 3e 64 5f 5f 33 00 00
    )
    .custom instance void [System.Diagnostics.Debug]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    // Method begins at RVA 0x206c
    // Code size 56 (0x38)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] class CS1998Test.Program/'<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'
    )

    IL_0000: newobj instance void CS1998Test.Program/'<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::.ctor()
    IL_0005: stloc.0
    IL_0006: ldloc.0
    IL_0007: call valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<!0> valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::Create()
    IL_000c: stfld valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::'<>t__builder'
    IL_0011: ldloc.0
    IL_0012: ldarg.0
    IL_0013: stfld class CS1998Test.Program CS1998Test.Program/'<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::'<>4__this'
    IL_0018: ldloc.0
    IL_0019: ldc.i4.m1
    IL_001a: stfld int32 CS1998Test.Program/'<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::'<>1__state'
    IL_001f: ldloc.0
    IL_0020: ldflda valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::'<>t__builder'
    IL_0025: ldloca.s 0
    IL_0027: call instance void valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::Start<class CS1998Test.Program/'<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'>(!!0&)
    IL_002c: ldloc.0
    IL_002d: ldflda valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::'<>t__builder'
    IL_0032: call instance class [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!0> valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::get_Task()
    IL_0037: ret
} // end of method Program::NotActuallyAsync

.class nested private auto ansi sealed beforefieldinit '<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'
    extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
    implements [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine
{
    .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    // Fields
    .field public int32 '<>1__state'
    .field public valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> '<>t__builder'
    .field public class CS1998Test.Program '<>4__this'

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x20fd
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        // {
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        // (no C# code)
        IL_0001: call instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()
        // }
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method '<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::.ctor

    .method private final hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance void MoveNext () cil managed 
    {
        .override method instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine::MoveNext()
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2108
        // Code size 58 (0x3a)
        .maxstack 2
        .locals init (
            [0] int32,
            [1] int32,
            [2] class [System.Runtime]System.Exception
        )

        // int num = <>1__state;
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldfld int32 CS1998Test.Program/'<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::'<>1__state'
        IL_0006: stloc.0
        .try
        {
            // result = 42;
            IL_0007: ldc.i4.s 42
            IL_0009: stloc.1
            // }
            IL_000a: leave.s IL_0024
        } // end .try
        catch [System.Runtime]System.Exception
        {
            // catch (Exception exception)
            IL_000c: stloc.2
            // <>1__state = -2;
            IL_000d: ldarg.0
            IL_000e: ldc.i4.s -2
            IL_0010: stfld int32 CS1998Test.Program/'<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::'<>1__state'
            // <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
            IL_0015: ldarg.0
            IL_0016: ldflda valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::'<>t__builder'
            IL_001b: ldloc.2
            IL_001c: call instance void valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::SetException(class [System.Runtime]System.Exception)
            // return;
            IL_0021: nop
            IL_0022: leave.s IL_0039
        } // end handler

        // <>1__state = -2;
        IL_0024: ldarg.0
        IL_0025: ldc.i4.s -2
        IL_0027: stfld int32 CS1998Test.Program/'<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::'<>1__state'
        // <>t__builder.SetResult(result);
        IL_002c: ldarg.0
        IL_002d: ldflda valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::'<>t__builder'
        IL_0032: ldloc.1
        IL_0033: call instance void valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::SetResult(!0)
        // }
        IL_0038: nop

        IL_0039: ret
    } // end of method '<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::MoveNext

    .method private final hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance void SetStateMachine (
            class [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [System.Diagnostics.Debug]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHiddenAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        .override method instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine::SetStateMachine(class [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine)
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2160
        // Code size 1 (0x1)
        .maxstack 8

        // }
        IL_0000: ret
    } // end of method '<NotActuallyAsync>d__3'::SetStateMachine

} // end of class <NotActuallyAsync>d__3

.method private hidebysig 
    instance class [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<int32> FullyAsync () cil managed 
{
    .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute::.ctor(class [System.Runtime]System.Type) = (
        01 00 23 43 53 31 39 39 38 54 65 73 74 2e 50 72
        6f 67 72 61 6d 2b 3c 46 75 6c 6c 79 41 73 79 6e
        63 3e 64 5f 5f 34 00 00
    )
    .custom instance void [System.Diagnostics.Debug]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    // Method begins at RVA 0x20b0
    // Code size 56 (0x38)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] class CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'
    )

    IL_0000: newobj instance void CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::.ctor()
    IL_0005: stloc.0
    IL_0006: ldloc.0
    IL_0007: call valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<!0> valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::Create()
    IL_000c: stfld valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>t__builder'
    IL_0011: ldloc.0
    IL_0012: ldarg.0
    IL_0013: stfld class CS1998Test.Program CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>4__this'
    IL_0018: ldloc.0
    IL_0019: ldc.i4.m1
    IL_001a: stfld int32 CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>1__state'
    IL_001f: ldloc.0
    IL_0020: ldflda valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>t__builder'
    IL_0025: ldloca.s 0
    IL_0027: call instance void valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::Start<class CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'>(!!0&)
    IL_002c: ldloc.0
    IL_002d: ldflda valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>t__builder'
    IL_0032: call instance class [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!0> valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::get_Task()
    IL_0037: ret
} // end of method Program::FullyAsync

.class nested private auto ansi sealed beforefieldinit '<FullyAsync>d__4'
    extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
    implements [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine
{
    .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    // Fields
    .field public int32 '<>1__state'
    .field public valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> '<>t__builder'
    .field public class CS1998Test.Program '<>4__this'
    .field private int32 '<>s__1'
    .field private valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<int32> '<>u__1'

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x217b
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        // {
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        // (no C# code)
        IL_0001: call instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()
        // }
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method '<FullyAsync>d__4'::.ctor

    .method private final hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance void MoveNext () cil managed 
    {
        .override method instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine::MoveNext()
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2184
        // Code size 199 (0xc7)
        .maxstack 3
        .locals init (
            [0] int32,
            [1] int32,
            [2] valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<int32>,
            [3] class CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4',
            [4] class [System.Runtime]System.Exception
        )

        // int num = <>1__state;
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldfld int32 CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>1__state'
        IL_0006: stloc.0
        .try
        {
            // if (num != 0)
            IL_0007: ldloc.0
            IL_0008: brfalse.s IL_000c

            // (no C# code)
            IL_000a: br.s IL_000e

            // awaiter = Task.Run(() => 42).GetAwaiter();
            IL_000c: br.s IL_0065

            IL_000e: ldsfld class [System.Runtime]System.Func`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<>c'::'<>9__4_0'
            IL_0013: dup
            IL_0014: brtrue.s IL_002d

            // (no C# code)
            IL_0016: pop
            // if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
            IL_0017: ldsfld class CS1998Test.Program/'<>c' CS1998Test.Program/'<>c'::'<>9'
            IL_001c: ldftn instance int32 CS1998Test.Program/'<>c'::'<FullyAsync>b__4_0'()
            IL_0022: newobj instance void class [System.Runtime]System.Func`1<int32>::.ctor(object, native int)
            IL_0027: dup
            IL_0028: stsfld class [System.Runtime]System.Func`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<>c'::'<>9__4_0'

            IL_002d: call class [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task::Run<int32>(class [System.Runtime]System.Func`1<!!0>)
            IL_0032: callvirt instance valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<!0> class [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<int32>::GetAwaiter()
            IL_0037: stloc.2
            IL_0038: ldloca.s 2
            IL_003a: call instance bool valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<int32>::get_IsCompleted()
            IL_003f: brtrue.s IL_0081

            // num = (<>1__state = 0);
            IL_0041: ldarg.0
            IL_0042: ldc.i4.0
            IL_0043: dup
            IL_0044: stloc.0
            IL_0045: stfld int32 CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>1__state'
            // <>u__1 = awaiter;
            IL_004a: ldarg.0
            IL_004b: ldloc.2
            IL_004c: stfld valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>u__1'
            // <FullyAsync>d__4 stateMachine = this;
            IL_0051: ldarg.0
            IL_0052: stloc.3
            // <>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref stateMachine);
            IL_0053: ldarg.0
            IL_0054: ldflda valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>t__builder'
            IL_0059: ldloca.s 2
            IL_005b: ldloca.s 3
            IL_005d: call instance void valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<int32>, class CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'>(!!0&, !!1&)
            // return;
            IL_0062: nop
            IL_0063: leave.s IL_00c6

            // awaiter = <>u__1;
            IL_0065: ldarg.0
            IL_0066: ldfld valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>u__1'
            IL_006b: stloc.2
            // <>u__1 = default(TaskAwaiter<int>);
            IL_006c: ldarg.0
            IL_006d: ldflda valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>u__1'
            IL_0072: initobj valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<int32>
            // num = (<>1__state = -1);
            IL_0078: ldarg.0
            IL_0079: ldc.i4.m1
            IL_007a: dup
            IL_007b: stloc.0
            IL_007c: stfld int32 CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>1__state'

            // <>s__1 = awaiter.GetResult();
            IL_0081: ldarg.0
            IL_0082: ldloca.s 2
            IL_0084: call instance !0 valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<int32>::GetResult()
            IL_0089: stfld int32 CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>s__1'
            // result = <>s__1;
            IL_008e: ldarg.0
            IL_008f: ldfld int32 CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>s__1'
            IL_0094: stloc.1
            // }
            IL_0095: leave.s IL_00b1
        } // end .try
        catch [System.Runtime]System.Exception
        {
            // catch (Exception exception)
            IL_0097: stloc.s 4
            // <>1__state = -2;
            IL_0099: ldarg.0
            IL_009a: ldc.i4.s -2
            IL_009c: stfld int32 CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>1__state'
            // <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
            IL_00a1: ldarg.0
            IL_00a2: ldflda valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>t__builder'
            IL_00a7: ldloc.s 4
            IL_00a9: call instance void valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::SetException(class [System.Runtime]System.Exception)
            // return;
            IL_00ae: nop
            IL_00af: leave.s IL_00c6
        } // end handler

        // <>1__state = -2;
        IL_00b1: ldarg.0
        IL_00b2: ldc.i4.s -2
        IL_00b4: stfld int32 CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>1__state'
        // <>t__builder.SetResult(result);
        IL_00b9: ldarg.0
        IL_00ba: ldflda valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32> CS1998Test.Program/'<FullyAsync>d__4'::'<>t__builder'
        IL_00bf: ldloc.1
        IL_00c0: call instance void valuetype [System.Threading.Tasks]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<int32>::SetResult(!0)
        // }
        IL_00c5: nop

        IL_00c6: ret
    } // end of method '<FullyAsync>d__4'::MoveNext

    .method private final hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance void SetStateMachine (
            class [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [System.Diagnostics.Debug]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHiddenAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        .override method instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine::SetStateMachine(class [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine)
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2268
        // Code size 1 (0x1)
        .maxstack 8

        // }
        IL_0000: ret
    } // end of method '<FullyAsync>d__4'::SetStateMachine

} // end of class <FullyAsync>d__4
```

In brief, executing a method marked with the `async` modifier entails the construction and execution of an asynchronous state machine for that method, **regardless of whether that method is actually performing any asynchronous work**! As I'm sure you can guess, that entails a performance penalty compared to a standard non-async method, which - depending on your use-case - may or may not be significant.

But this isn't what the CS1998 warning says at all. This warning is intended for the case where you've defined an `async` method because you need to await something in it, but have simply forgotten to add the `await` keyword before the asynchronous call.

Your case is essentially the opposite: you've defined a method as `async` but you know and intend that it doesn't perform any such work. But the compiler has no way of knowing that - to the compiler it looks exactly the same as the previous case, so you get the same warning.

To be honest, in that second case **you yourself have caused the warning by unnecessarily adding the `async` keyword to the implementation**. You know that the method isn't doing any asynchronous work, so why bother adding the keyword? You're just bloating it for no good reason.

The warning could certainly be improved to call out the fact that you're basically being silly, [and I've opened an issue in the Roslyn repo to hopefully get that done](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/50522).

Answer (score 6):

Michael Liu answered well your question about how you can avoid the warning: by returning Task.FromResult.

I'm going to answer the "Should I worry about the warning" part of your question.

The answer is Yes!

The reason for this is that the warning frequently results when you call a method that returns `Task` inside of an async method without the `await` operator.  I just fixed a concurrency bug that happened because I invoked an operation in Entity Framework without awaiting the previous operation.

If you can meticulously write your code to avoid compiler warnings, then when there is a warning, it will stand out like a sore thumb.  I could have avoided several hours of debugging.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. Here's why: there can be at least one `await` inside the method in one place (there will be no CS1998) but it doesn't mean that there will be no other call of asnyc method that will lack the synchronization (using `await` or any other). Now if someone would like to know how to make sure you don't miss the synchronization accidentally then just make sure you don't ignore another warning - CS4014. I would even recommend to threat that one as error.

Answer (score 2):

## Note on exception behaviour when returning `Task.FromResult`

Here's a little demo which shows the difference in exception handling between methods  marked and not marked with `async`.

```
public Task<string> GetToken1WithoutAsync() => throw new Exception("Ex1!");

// Warning: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider ...
public async Task<string> GetToken2WithAsync() => throw new Exception("Ex2!");  

public string GetToken3Throws() => throw new Exception("Ex3!");
public async Task<string> GetToken3WithAsync() => await Task.Run(GetToken3Throws);

public async Task<string> GetToken4WithAsync() { throw new Exception("Ex4!"); return await Task.FromResult("X");} 

        
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = new Program();
    
    try { var task1 = p.GetToken1WithoutAsync(); } 
    catch( Exception ) { Console.WriteLine("Throws before await.");};

    var task2 = p.GetToken2WithAsync(); // Does not throw;
    try { var token2 = await task2; } 
    catch( Exception ) { Console.WriteLine("Throws on await.");};

    var task3 = p.GetToken3WithAsync(); // Does not throw;
    try { var token3 = await task3; } 
    catch( Exception ) { Console.WriteLine("Throws on await.");};
 
    var task4 = p.GetToken4WithAsync(); // Does not throw;
    try { var token4 = await task4; } 
    catch( Exception ) { Console.WriteLine("Throws on await.");};
}
```

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
Throws before await.
Throws on await.
Throws on await.
Throws on await.
```

*(Cross post of my answer for [What is the best way to return completed Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407904/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-completed-task))*

Comment: I've just hit an interesting issue regarding this. Because I had an interface that was returning a Task, but my a few of my concrete implementations had nothing to asynchronously call, and some of them needed to return null to exit early, I had been using return Task.FromResult(<ReturnClass>null);. The interesting weird side effect that I had not expected was that when the method raised an exception, the only clue was a "object not set to an instance of an object" exception, but on the line calling the async method, which made zero sense at the time and took me a while to debug. Nice answer!