# Does order of calling matter in terms of Task.CompletedTask?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, synchronous

What are the differences?
What problems I am introducing with these each approach?
Is there any better way to 'wrap' sync call?

```
async Task Method()
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;
    externalService.syncCall();
}
```

```
async Task Method()
{
    externalService.syncCall();
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

```
Task Method()
{
    externalService.syncCall();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: The bottom (third) example, the one _without_ the `async` modifier, is the best one, imo. The first and second examples are silly because there is zero reason to `await Task.CompletedTask`.

Comment: @Dai `await Task.CompletedTask` is one way to suppress the CS1998 warning. As for the 3rd being "best",  if `syncCall` throws then it breaks the expected exception semantics of an asynchronous function.

Comment: In what type of application do you intend to use the `Method` method? WinForms? ASP.NET? Console app?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay If you're getting CS1998 then just remove the `await` modifier. I am aware that those kinds of methods [_should_ have their own `try/catch` and use `Task.FromException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542514/how-do-i-handle-exceptions-when-resolving-warning-cs1998-this-async-method-lack) but in-practice I haven't had any problem with not doing that, but I'm curious what your experiences are.

Comment: @Dai It's a nuanced scenario, but I wouldn't recommend a quick and dirty solution without having more context than this question currently contains.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Very correct!

Comment: You might enjoy this blog post by Stephen Cleary: [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Answer (score 2):

On the assumption that this method *needs* to return a `Task` due to interface constraints:

The first 2 are loosely equivalent and will behave in the same way.

The third will be *slightly* more efficient because it bypasses the state machine generated by the `async` keyword, **however**, eliding `async` makes you responsible for exception handling, and the current implementation is likely incomplete.

The consumer of an asynchronous (`Task`-returning) method expects exceptions to be thrown *only at the point the `Task` is awaited*.

For example:

```
var task = SomeMethodAsync();

// Do some other stuff..

await task; // Exception here if thrown in SomeMethodAsync()
```

Now if `externalService.syncCall()` throws in your `Method()`, this will happen:

```
var task = Method(); // Exception thrown here

// Do some other stuff..

await task;
```

To ensure `Method()` behaves as per the first example, you could do something like this:

```
Task Method()
{
    try { externalService.syncCall(); }
    catch (Exception e) { return Task.FromException(e); }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: To imitate completely the behavior of the `async` method, you also have to add this: `catch (OperationCanceledException oce) { return Task.FromCanceled(oce.CancellationToken); }`. Which is kind of ridiculous. If you have time to spend for this kind of micro-optimization, most probably you could spend it on other areas of your project, and reap much bigger benefits. This one might give you a few nanoseconds per operation at best.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias That would be ridiculous, unless `syncCall` is likely to throw an `OperationCanceledException`, and the consumer of `Method` needs to be able to differentiate between cancelled and other faulted tasks. A cancelled `Task` still throws when awaited which is the key consideration.

Comment: Johnathan if you are not going to imitate completely the behavior of an `async` method, then you might as well not `catch` any exception at all, and just assume that the caller of the method will invoke and then `await` it in one step: `await SomeMethodAsync();`. This is by far the most common usage pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the differences?

The first two are essentially the same, although they're both doing unnecessary work with the `await Task.CompletedTask;`. I would say `await Task.CompletedTask` is a code smell, since it's really just adding code to do a noop in order to make a compiler warning go away. The compiler warning is there for a reason, and adding code just to silence it is missing the point of the warning.

The third one is quite different as soon as exceptions come into play. With Task-returning methods, callers expect exceptions to be placed on the returned task, but this one will throw them directly before returning the task.

> Is there any better way to 'wrap' sync call?

The best way is to [not](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/):

```
void Method() => externalService.syncCall();
```

But sometimes you may need to. E.g., if you're implementing an interface that has a `Task`-returning `Method`. In that case, I recommend using a `#pragma` to disable the compiler warning. This has two advantages over `await Task.CompletedTask`: first, it explicitly notes in the code "I have considered this warning and evaluated it as spurious in this situation"; second, it doesn't add actual *code* just to do a noop.

```
#pragma warning disable 1998 // This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
async Task Method()
#pragma warning restore 1998 // This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
{
    externalService.syncCall();
}
```

If you need to do this often, collecting the `#pragma`s into a [helper type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/0361015459938f2eb8f3c1ad1021d19ee01c93a4/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskHelper.cs) would be cleaner.

Comment: `#pragma` directives are so ugly though! Even if you hide it in a helper method, it's still an eye sorrow.

Comment: I agree, but IMO code that exists just to silence a compiler warning (as opposed to correcting it) is worse. :)